# Create custom form with rating stars after order

Tags: magento2, review, product-review, ratings

I'm trying to create a custom form that I will send by email after X days order and there they will be able to put rating stars for the delivery, the experience with the store among others.
Can I use  magento rating reviews or I'll need to create customizations around this? I mean, can rating review only be used for products or can i use this for what i need? Because I don't want to have to calculate the star value to get the rating average since magento already has that for product rating and I just want to take advantage of that logic. Can anyone tell me or show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**As per Your Requirement, you can TRY this Module :**

[Magento 2 Review Reminder](https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-review-reminder.html)

**I think this extension fulfills your requirement.**